# How can I have the main repository stored on a local network?

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I'm wondering how can I have the main Mercurial repository stored on the local network and every developer connected to it can do the usual things (just like with BitBucket online.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/PublishingRepositories
If it's only on a local network, `hg serve` is the easiest/fastest with 0 auth support.
of course you can always use ssh without the need of setting up a server.
`hg clone ssh://your-main-server/path/to/repo`

Comment: Thanks but this is only working though my machine when I try to access it through: http://localhost:8000/. So I have two questions: 1. Will the other users be able to push updates or they can pull only? 2. How can I make http://localhost:8000/ accessible though the network?

Comment: By default it listens on all interfaces here, but you can try `hg serve -a 0.0.0.0` or replace 0.0.0.0 with the lan ip.
and you need to add `[web]
allow_push = *` your project's .hgrc to allow pushing.

Comment: Thanks that worked very well but how can I have multiple projects using this method?

Comment: For multiple repos you should use hgwebdir Like Wim said, check http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/PublishingRepositories#multiple. that however requires a webserver with CGI support.

Answer (score 2):

1. Set up a machine running the [apache HTTP server](http://httpd.apache.org/) (or another webserver that can host hgwebdir)
2. [Install the hgwebdir CGI script](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/HgWebDirStepByStep).